# PyQt configuration and installation error

Tags: macos, qt, pyqt, maya, python-sip

I'm trying to install PyQt for Maya on my Macbook pro. I've succesfully installed Qt and Sip and I'm failing to install PyQt.

The versions I'm using are

OSX 10.6.8, Qt 4.7.1 - modified Autodesk Qt, Sip 4.13.2, PyQt 4.9.1

When configuring pyqt it succeeds but when building it fails. I think it might have something to do with the directory /Users/warnold being used in the configuration. It's listed four times but the directory doesn't exist and I don't know where it came from. Qt is installed at /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.1

Configuration I get the following:

```
export QTDIR=/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.1/
export PATH=/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.1/bin:$PATH
export QMAKESPEC=/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.1/mkspecs/macx-g++
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.1/lib/
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2013/Maya.app/Contents/bin/mayapy configure.py LIBDIR_QT=/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.1/lib INCDIR_QT=/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.1/include MOC=/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.1/bin/moc --no-designer-plugin --use-arch=x86_64

Determining the layout of your Qt installation...
This is the GPL version of PyQt 4.9.1 (licensed under the GNU General Public
License) for Python 2.6.4 on darwin.

Type '2' to view the GPL v2 license.
Type '3' to view the GPL v3 license.
Type 'yes' to accept the terms of the license.
Type 'no' to decline the terms of the license.

Do you accept the terms of the license? yes             
Found the license file pyqt-gpl.sip.
Checking to see if the QtGui module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtHelp module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtMultimedia module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtNetwork module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtDBus module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtDeclarative module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtOpenGL module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtScript module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtScriptTools module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtSql module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtSvg module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtTest module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtWebKit module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtXml module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtXmlPatterns module should be built...
Checking to see if the phonon module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtAssistant module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtDesigner module should be built...
Qt v4.7.1 free edition is being used.
SIP 4.13.2 is being used.
The Qt header files are in /Users/warnold/qt/qt-4.7.1/include.
The shared Qt libraries are in /Users/warnold/qt/qt-4.7.1/lib.
The Qt binaries are in /Users/warnold/qt/qt-4.7.1/bin.
The Qt mkspecs directory is in /Users/warnold/qt/qt-4.7.1.
These PyQt modules will be built: QtCore.
The PyQt Python package will be installed in
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2013/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.6/site-packages.
PyQt is being built with generated docstrings.
PyQt is being built with 'protected' redefined as 'public'.
The PyQt .sip files will be installed in
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2013/Maya.app/Contents/bin/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/share/sip/PyQt4.
pyuic4, pyrcc4 and pylupdate4 will be installed in
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2013/Maya.app/Contents/bin/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin.
Generating the C++ source for the QtCore module...
Creating the Makefile for the QtCore module...
Generating the C++ source for the Qt module...
Creating the Makefile for the Qt module...
Creating QScintilla API file...
Creating top level Makefile...
Creating QPy support library for QtCore Makefile...
Creating QPy support libraries Makefile...
Creating pyuic4 wrapper...
Creating pyuic4 Makefile...
pylupdate4 and pyrcc4 will not be built because the Qt XML module is missing.
Creating pyqtconfig.py...
Exception TypeError: TypeError("'NoneType' object is not callable",) in <bound method Popen.__del__ of <subprocess.Popen object at 0x100495450>> ignored
```

building I get a bunch of code which ends with

```
ld: library not found for -lQtCore
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [QtCore.so] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm at a complete loss. Not sure how to rectify this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I have a detailed write-up on this topic already:
http://www.justinfx.com/2011/11/09/installing-pyqt4-for-maya-2012-osx/

It also contains ready built packages for you to install, including Maya 2013 for Lion. I have not tried the Lion package on Snow Leopard but I suspect it should work since it was built with the same SDK and arch.

I had created a repo to store build scripts for each maya version:
https://github.com/justinfx/MyQt4

And the original write up for Maya 2011 manual PyQt installation:
http://www.justinfx.com/2011/01/07/installing-pyqt-for-maya-2011-osx/
You can still apply this same procedure to newer versions, by just updating the package versions of Qt, Sip, PyQt to the appropriate ones. But the idea of the MyQt repo was to take the frustration out of it and just do it from a script.

Comment: Thanks. I was following the instructions on your website for installing but missed the prebuilt package. That helped greatly. Admittingly, I'm completely confused as to how it's working though. I'm used to windows and installing things with an installer.