# ld library errors when building pyqt for maya 2013 on osx 10.6

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, maya, python-sip

I am having similar errors to this [PyQt configuration and installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571796/pyqt-configuration-and-installation-error)

I really need to figure it out rather that use the packages that were offered as a solution to the original posts question (I need control of the Install locations for my development environment. Can anyone shed some light on what the install isnt finding and why?

The following commands are being used to build python, qt, sip and pyqt.

I am mostly trying to use these instructions as a guide http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/pyqtmaya2013.pdf

```
# build python as a linux style package
cd /4degrees/users/medwards/src
tar xvfz /Users/medwards/Desktop/python/Python-2.6.4.tgz
cd Python-2.6.4
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/python/2.6.4
make
sudo make install

export PATH=/4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/python/2.6.4bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/python/2.6.4/lib/python2.6/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/python/2.6.4/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# build QT
cd /4degrees/users/medwards/src
tar xzf /Users/medwards/Desktop/python/Qt-4.7.1-Maya/qt-adsk-4.7.1.tgz
cd qt-adsk-4.7.1
./configure -prefix /4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/Qt/4.7.1 -arch x86_64 -debug-and-release -no-rpath -silent -no-qt3support
make -j 4 >& build.log
sudo make install

# build sip
export PATH=/4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/python/2.6.4bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/python/2.6.4/lib/python2.6/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/python/2.6.4/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=/4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/Qt/4.7.1/bin:$PATH

cd /4degrees/users/medwards/src
tar -zxvf /Users/medwards/Desktop/python/sip-4.13.3.tar.gz
cd sip-4.13.3
/Applications/Autodesk/maya2013/Maya.app/Contents/bin/mayapy ./configure.py -b /4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/sip/4.13.3/mayapy2013/bin -d /4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/sip/4.13.3/mayapy2013/site-packages -e /4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/sip/4.13.3/mayapy2013/include -v /4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/sip/4.13.3/mayapy2013/sip
make
sudo make install

# build pyqt
export PATH=/4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/python/2.6.4bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/python/2.6.4/lib/python2.6/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/python/2.6.4/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=/4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/Qt/4.7.1/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/sip/4.13.3/mayapy2013/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/sip/4.13.3/mayapy2013/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH

cd /4degrees/users/medwards/src
tar -zxvf /Users/medwards/Desktop/python/PyQt-mac-gpl-4.9.4.tar.gz
cd PyQt-mac-gpl-4.9.4

# change inc_path = [sipcfg.py_inc_dir] to inc_path = [sipcfg.py_inc_dir,sipcfg.sip_inc_dir] in PyQt-mac-gpl-4.9.4/configure.py

/Applications/Autodesk/maya2013/Maya.app/Contents/bin/mayapy configure.py LIBDIR_QT=/4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/Qt/4.7.1/lib INCDIR_QT=/4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/Qt/4.7.1/include MOC=/4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/Qt/4.7.1/bin/moc -b /4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/python/mayapy2011/bin -d /4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/python/mayapy2013/lib/python2.6/site-packages -v /4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/sip/4.13.3/mayapy2013/sip --no-designer-plugin --use-arch=x86_64 -w

# edit qtdirs.out and replace /Users/warnold/qt/qt-4.7.1 with /4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/Qt/4.7.1

make -j 4
sudo make install
```

During make I end up with something along the lines of

```
...-L/4degrees/users/medwards/src/PyQt-mac-gpl-4.9.4/qpy/QtCore -L/4degrees/prod/lib/MacOSX_X86_64/Qt/4.7.1/lib -lqpycore -lQtCore
ld: library not found for -lQtCore
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [QtCore.so] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```